# Python's literal_eval says string 'a,b,c' is malformed

Tags: python, eval, literals

[`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) documentation states:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a **Unicode** or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: **strings**, numbers, **tuples**, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

I want to parse a unicode string representing a tuple. Why do I get `ValueError: malformed string` for the following inputs?

```
print literal_eval(unicode('abc')) 
print literal_eval(unicode('c,d,e'))
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 84, in literal_eval
    return _convert(node_or_string)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 55, in _convert
    return tuple(map(_convert, node.elts))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ast.py", line 83, in _convert
    raise ValueError('malformed node or string: ' + repr(node))
ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7f1da47e7860>
```

However, this example does work:

```
print literal_eval(unicode('1,2,3'))
(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`literal_eval` only parses [literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals).  Your string is a tuple of variable names (`abc`, `c`, `d`, `e`).  Instead, you want either a tuple of strings or a string with commas.  Either one requires two levels of quotes.

```
# string
print(literal_eval("'abc'"))
'abc'
print(literal_eval("'c,d,e'"))
'c,d,e'

# tuple of strings
print(literal_eval("'c','d','e'"))
('c', 'd', 'e')
```

Your last example is a tuple of ints, which are all literals, so it parses successfully.